# Calculate u in terms of time such that a particle maintains a constant speed following a parametric equation

Tags: parametric

I have a parametric equation given by:
$x=\cos(6u)$
$y=\sin(4u)$

And I understand that the speed of a particle at any given t is:
$\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{dx}{du}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac {dy}{du} \right)^2} $

Which for my parametric equation would be:
$\sqrt{36 \sin^2(6u) + 16 \cos^2(4u)}$

I am trying to make a particle move at a constant speed along the parametric equation.

I have looked and seem to be unable to find information on how to do this, the only thing I did find is [this paper on the subject](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/MovingAlongCurveSpecifiedSpeed.pdf).

Unfortunately given my rather basic grasp of calculus I wasn't able to make much sense of it.

To clarify, I am looking for $u$ in terms of time such that the particle maintains constant speed.

Thanks.

Comment: The derivatives are wrong: it should be $\;x'=-6\sin6t\;,\;\;y'=4\cos4t\;$ . Not that this will make the expression in the square root nicer, but at least it will make it correct.

Comment: My mistake, thank you for pointing it out. Updated.

Comment: You're welcome. Now, for any given $\;t\;$ **that is** (i.e., what you wrote in the square root) the speed of the particle. What else do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to do the opposite, that is choose a speed and from this find t with the aim of then using t to simulate a particle following the graph given by the parametric equation at a constant speed. This assumes the particle moves/(x, y) are recalculated once every x seconds.

Comment: From your speed equation we must assume that $t$ is time. But then your final equation says that the speed of the particle is **not** constant! If you want constant speed, then you'll need a new parameter.

Comment: so you want to force it to go round at constant speed by, in some sense, undoing this sine/cosine expression?

Comment: Given any curve $\gamma(t)$, you can find reparametrization $r(t)$ so that $\beta(t) = \gamma(r(t))$ has derivative with norm 1. It is called arc length parametrization:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_curves#Length_and_natural_parametrization

Comment: PM 2Ring - Yes I want constant speed, I shouldn't have called the parameter t as for my purposes is is just a number which will be incremented on a timer and I am trying to determine how much to increment it each time.

danimal - exactly, sorry I'm not very clear with what I am attempting to do.

Sina - thanks for the link, I sort of understand it, I'm going to spend a bit of time trying to work it out for myself.

Comment: @TenEighty: Ok. In that case, your speed equation is incorrect. You should edit your question to use a different letter for the parameter in your first 2 equations (eg $u$). So you're looking for a function that gives $u$ in terms of $t$ such that the particle speed is constant. I suspect that this is a very hard problem - there may not be a closed-form solution, but I suppose it'll be easy enough to approximate numerically on a computer.

Comment: BTW, you should use the `@name` notation if you want people to know that you've responded to their comments.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you, I have edited my question. It is ok if there is no closed form soloution, an approximation is fine as I just need to give the appearance of constant speed in a visual simulation program.

Comment: Now you need to multiply your speed equations by $du/dt$. Do you see why?

Comment: @TenEighty: The general idea is to let $s$ denote the _arc length function_ along your curve, and to use $s$ as a parameter. The "catch" is, $s$ is the definite integral of the speed, and to use $s$ as a parameter you must "solve for $s$ as a function of $t$", i.e., invert a function defined by an integral. Since your arc length integral is probably _not elementary_ ("cannot be evaluated in closed form") you don't have much hope of a symbolic parametrization (as PM 2Ring says). Are you making an interactive simulation, or a static animation?

Comment: @PM2Ring I think so, I'm not sure how to do this though.

Comment: @user86418 ok, I am beginning to understand a bit more. I guess you would call it an interactive simulation - the calculations need to happen in real time as it is rendered.

Answer (score 2):

As Yves Daoust explained, you can use one of the Runge-Kutta methods to numerically solve the differential equation for your parameter. However, if the step size is small (the speed is low) you can get by with simple [Euler integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method). In other words,

$\frac{\Delta u}{\Delta t} \approx \frac{du}{dt}$

so just let $\Delta u = \Delta t \cdot \frac{du}{dt}$

To optimize this calculation we can express the arc length differential in terms of $x$ and $y$. The equations below use $a$ and $b$ for the $x$ & $y$ frequencies, rather than your 6 & 4, in order to make the result apply to any Lissajous figure. They also use $\theta$ for the parameter; I figured that was appropriate because we're dealing with trigonometric functions, and I guess it looks a little more professional. :)

$$\begin{align}
\text{Let } x & = \cos (a \theta), \, y = \sin (b \theta) \\
\frac{dx}{d\theta} & = - a \sin (a \theta), \, \frac{dy}{d\theta} = b \cos (b \theta) \\
\\
\frac{ds}{d\theta}^2 & = \frac{dx}{d\theta}^2 + \frac{dy}{d\theta}^2 \\
& = a^2 \sin^2 (a \theta) + b^2 \cos^2 (b \theta) \\
& = a^2 (1 - \cos^2 (a \theta)) + b^2 (1 - \sin^2 (b \theta)) \\
& = a^2 (1 - x^2) + b^2 (1 - y^2) \\
\frac{ds}{d\theta} & = \sqrt{a^2 (1 - x^2) + b^2 (1 - y^2)}\\
\\
v & = \frac{ds}{dt} = \frac{ds}{d\theta} \cdot \frac{d\theta}{dt}\\
\\
\text{Therefore}\\
\frac{d\theta}{dt} & = \frac{v}{ds/d\theta}\\
\Delta\theta & \approx \frac{\Delta t \cdot v}{ds/d\theta}\\
& = \frac{\Delta t \cdot v}{\sqrt{a^2 (1 - x^2) + b^2 (1 - y^2)}}
\end{align}$$

Here's a small Python snippet to illustrate the algorithm:

```
def liss(a, b, speed, width, height):
    pix = bitmap(width, height)
    ox, oy = width // 2, height // 2
    rad = min(ox, oy) - 3

    #Precompute constants used in speed calculation
    r2 = rad * rad
    a2 = a * a
    b2 = b * b
    c2 = (a2 + b2) * r2

    maxtheta = 2. * pi
    theta = 0.0
    while theta < maxtheta:
        x = rad * cos(a * theta)
        y = rad * sin(b * theta)
        pix.put(int(.5 + ox + x), int(.5 + oy + y))
        dtheta = speed / (c2 - a2 * x*x - b2 * y*y) ** 0.5
        theta += dtheta
```

Here's the output of the above algorithm, with a=3, b=2, speed=10:

[image: Lissajous by Euler integration]

As you can see, it's fairly smooth. But we can make it better by following Yves' advice and using Runge-Kutta integration. Here's Python code that uses RK4:

```
def liss(a, b, speed, width, height):
    pix = bitmap(width, height)
    ox, oy = width // 2, height // 2
    rad = min(ox, oy) - 3

    def speedfunc(theta):
        s = (a * sin(a * theta))**2 + (b * cos(b * theta))**2
        return speed / (rad * s ** 0.5)

    maxtheta = 2. * pi
    theta = 0.0
    while theta < maxtheta:
        x = rad * cos(a * theta)
        y = rad * sin(b * theta)
        pix.put(int(.5 + ox + x), int(.5 + oy + y))

        #Calculate Runge-Kutta 4 increments
        k1 = speedfunc(theta)
        k2 = speedfunc(theta + 0.5 * k1)
        k3 = speedfunc(theta + 0.5 * k2)
        k4 = speedfunc(theta + k3)

        dtheta = (k1 + 2.0 * k2 + 2.0 * k3 + k4) / 6.0
        theta += dtheta
```

And its output, with the same parameters as above:

[image: Lissajous by RK4 integration]

It's hard to see much difference here, but the RK4 algorithm is clearly superior for high speeds, especially in the regions of the curve where the acceleration is high.

In case you're interested, here's a Pastebin link to the full Python 2 program used to produce the RK4 version as a plain [PBM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pbm.html) file; you can easily adapt it to use the Euler algorithm. This program was tested on Python 2.6 but it probably runs on earlier versions; it will need minor modifications to run on Python 3.

[LissRK4.py](http://pastebin.com/rST4YTXx)

Finally, I'd like to mention that although these constant speed algorithms make nice-looking plots, I have to agree with user86418 that the simple constant angle increment algorithm looks more natural in an animation; after all, this *is* simple harmonic motion. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Generalities**: Suppose a plane parametric curve is defined by $x = f(t)$ and $y = g(t)$ for $a \leq t \leq b$. (For technical reasons, assume $f$ and $g$ have continuous first derivatives, and that the curve's velocity is never $(0, 0)$, i.e., $f'$ and $g'$ never vanish at the same point.)

The *speed* of the curve is
$$
s'(t) = \sqrt{f'(t)^{2} + g'(t)^{2}},
$$
and the *arc length function* $s$ on $[a, b]$ is defined by
$$
s(t) = \int_{a}^{t} \sqrt{f'(u)^{2} + g'(u)^{2}}\, du.
$$
For convenience, let $\ell = s(b)$ denote the *length* of the curve.

Since $s' > 0$ (the velocity is non-vanishing, so the speed is positive), $s:[a, b] \to [0, \ell]$ is strictly increasing, and therefore has a differentiable inverse function $\tau:[0, \ell] \to [a, b]$. By the chain rule and the formula for the derivative of an inverse function, the parametrization
$$
x = f \circ \tau,\quad
y = g \circ \tau
$$
has speed $s'(t)\, \tau'(s) = 1$.

---

**Specifics**: For the curve in this question, $x = \cos(6t)$ and $y = \sin(4t)$ are $\pi$-periodic, and the arc length function is given by
$$
s(t) = \int_{0}^{t} \sqrt{36 \sin^{2}(6u) + 16 \cos^{2}(4u)}\, du,\quad
0 \leq t \leq \pi.
$$
As above, put
$$
\ell
  = s(\pi)
  = \int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt{36 \sin^{2}(6u) + 16 \cos^{2}(4u)}\, du.
$$

Let's suppose the animation is to have $N$ "position steps", i.e., the particle can be at any of $N$ distinct locations. (In the diagram, $N = 120$.)

[image: 120 points on a Lissajous figure]

One (inflexible, and therefore possibly inelegant) approach would be to *pre-compute* (and store in the program) $N$ values $t_{i}$, $1 \leq i \leq N$, for which
$$
s(t_{i}) \approx \frac{i}{N}\, \ell,
$$
namely, to calculate the $t$ values for which the particle is $(i/N)$ of the way along the curve *with respect to arc length*. Then, when the program needs to display the particle at "the $i$th position", it plots $\bigl(f(t_{i}), g(t_{i})\bigr)$. (Symmetry of the speed for this curve allows the position to be reconstructed from $N/4$ points, in case that's helpful.)

---

**Note**: The original parametrization, the "shadow" of a point moving at constant speed along an imaginary surface (a flat torus in four-dimensional space if it matters), may look more "natural" than a constant-speed parametrization. That is, don't expend a lot of computational effort to make the motion look "forced" unless you're positive that's what you want or need.

Answer (score 0):

An easy numerical solution is obtained by solving the differential equation for $u$ as a function of $t$:

$$V=\frac{ds}{dt}=\frac{ds}{du}\frac{du}{dt},$$
or
$$\frac{du}{dt}=\frac V{\sqrt{36 \sin^2(6u) + 16 \cos^2(4u)}}.$$

Use the [Runge-Kutta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) method.